# JS Javascript - How to put array values in another array by indexes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have this array/object:

```
const template = {0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]}
// I have the above but happy to convert the below if it helps:
//const templateArr = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]]
```

Then I have an array that I want to map into that sequence:

```
const myArray = ["Q","W","A","S","Z","X,"E","R","D"] // for example
```

My intention it to have following result:

```
let myResult = [["Q", "W", "A", "S", "Z", "X"],["Q", "W", "A", "S", "Z", "E"]]
```

So all the values of `myArray` are in the positions set by `template`.

I'm not sure if I should use `.map()` or something else... Can someone point me in the right direction??

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `.map()` is the right tool here. You can use two, one outer one to map over your inner arrays from `templateArr`, and then an inner map to map over the numbers (indexes) in your inner arrays, which will transform (ie: map) each number to the corresponding value at the index from `myArray`:

```js
const templateArr = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]];
const myArray = ["Q","W","A","S","Z","X","E","R","D"];

const res = templateArr.map(inner => inner.map(idx => myArray[idx]));
console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); // JSON.stringify to pretty-print
```

Comment: If u have object then instead of `templateArr.map` it can be `Object.values(template).map` or `Object.keys(template).map(k=> template[k].map())`

Answer (score 1):

`Object.values` will convert your `template` into array of arrays, then simply do map over it and another inner map over indicies and replace
them with particular letter from `myArray`.

Code:

```js
const template = {0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]}

const myArray = ["Q","W","A","S","Z","X","E","R","D"]

const res = Object.values(template)
                  .map(a => a.map(idx => myArray[idx] ?? null))

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; } /* ignore this */
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
const res = templateArr.map( (arr) => {
    
    return arr.map( (index) => {
        return myArray[index]
    })
})
```